# Core Data Model editing hangs in XCode 3.2.5

Tags: xcode, core-data, freeze

In XCode 3.2.5, when I right- or left-click on a .xcdatamodel file in my project, the program hangs with a spinning beach-volley "forever".

Any idea what might be causing this, or what I can do to allow the file to open smoothly? This also happens if I copy the file out of the project and try to open it by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a known bug for Apple, bug #8357795